# Discord.py: Going through a specific channel's history, picking a random image and sending it's link

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to find a way to pick a random attachment from the chat history of the channel but I've searched everywhere and I'm still having trouble.. Please help, thanks.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to efficienly do this. You probably need to read through the message history back until you're satisfied with the time interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Send a Random Attachment from the channel history

If we're speaking about [discord.Attachment](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Attachment) only, the following code will work "fine".

> ⚠️ Warning: As mention in the documentation, retrieves every message in the channel is a process that can slow significantly your command process.

With the following steps:

1. Get channel's messages history
2. Keep only Attachments
3. Keep only attachements url (from images)
4. Send a random attachment url in the chat

```py
@commands.command(name="example")
async def example(self, ctx: commands.Context):
    
    # Step 1.
    messages = [ # List of messages history
        # delete the 'limit' parameter to get all messages
        message 
        async for message in ctx.channel.history(limit=100)
    ]

    # Step 2.
    message_attachments = [ # List of attachments
        message.attachments 
        for message in messages 
        if message.attachments
    ]

    # Step 3.
    image_attachments = [ # List of image attachments
        attachment.url 
        for attachments in message_attachments 
        for attachment in attachments 
        # Remove this condition if you want all attachments
        if attachment.url.endswith(".png") or attachment.url.endswith(".jpg") or attachment.url.endswith(".gif")
    ]

    # Step 4.
    if len(image_attachments) > 0:
        # Pick up a random number from index 0 to last index of our image list
        random_number = random.randint(0, len(image_attachments))

        # Send the attachment
        await ctx.send(image_attachments[random_number])

    else:
        await ctx.send("No image found.")
```

Documentation references (discord.py):

- [discord.TextChannel.history](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history)
- [discord.Attachments](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Attachment)

Comment: thanks so much, discord.py is a little confusing for me